# Fonte embutida com nome composto não é exibida

Tags: c#, wpf

Estou embutindo algumas fontes no meu aplicativo WPF mas algumas não são exibidas.

As fontes estão na pasta /Fonts na raiz do aplicativo e suas propriedades estão definidas como Resource.

Uso assim:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Fonts/#Pericles"   />

<TextBlock FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Fonts/#Pericles Light"   />
```

Neste caso, "**#Pericles**" cujo nome é simples, exibe normalmente. Já "**#Pericles Light**" que tem nome composto, não exibe. Embora vários exemplos que encontrei sugerem esta forma, acredito que deve haver algum caractere de escape para os espaços no nome da fonte. Será?

Comment: Você quer dizer ``\``?

Comment: Acredito que barra invertida não funciona no XAML. Tentei &#160; sem sucesso. :(

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução é adicionar o nome do arquivo de fonte:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Fonts/PERICL.TTF#Pericles Light"   />
```